# Animate background in activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-animation

I would like to have an animated background in my activity (animation such a translation or zoom on a image).
To give you an example the twitter app made this on the login activity. It slowly zoom on the background image as below :

[image: Begin]
[image: End]

I didn't find any solution to move a drawable set with

```
getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable()
```

Should I use an ImageView as background widget and then perform animation by changing the source image ?

Any ideas on how can I do this ?

Comment: You already answered, put an ImageView in full screen as a background and animate it

Comment: Any better optimized solution?

Comment: Since a background animation would redraw the full screen continuously, I don't think you can optimize this.

Answer (score 1):

i think following link useful to you

https://github.com/Tprasanth/SplashScreenZoom